# SQL Server Remote Debugging Across Different Domains

Tags: sql-server, remote-debugging

I'm running VS2008 on my client machine and I'm running SQL 2000 on the remote db server which is on a different domain. I am able to remote desktop to the remote computer and use query analyser to debug, however it doesn't work when I try it remotely. I don't get any errors and when I try and step into the sp it doesn't halt.

From the research I have done it looks like the client PC is trying to attach to a process on the remote machine. However since this is on an another domain the user that VS 2008 uses won't be able to authenticate with the remote machine.

I believe this possible but my question is what do I need to configure to make this work, or is there any additional software that I require for this. I've tried using the VS Remote debugging monitor on the db server, but not sure whether I'm barking up the wrong tree with this.

Thanks

Comment: From my experiences with SQL Server 2000 debugging, I'm impressed you've even managed to get it working "locally" (i.e. when Query Analyzer and server are the same machine)

Answer (score 0):

The knowledgebase article [INF: Transact-SQL Debugger Limitations and Troubleshooting Tips for SQL Server 2000](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;280101) may still be relevant/helpful (although obviously, they've fixed the first mentioned limitation concerning terminal services/remote desktop)